# How do I properly cleanup an AVCaptureSession and AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, ios4

I'm using the AVFoundation api to create a camera preview view and I'm having trouble cleaning up after I'm done.

The best answer I've found to this problem is in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741121/how-to-properly-release-an-avcapturesession/3858077#3858077), thanks Codo.

However, he doesn't address the deallocation of the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, and that's where I'm having trouble.

In my view controller class I have some initialization code in a startCameraCapture method. Listening to Codo's answer, I'm using `dispatch_set_finalizer_f(_captureQueue, capture_cleanup);` to register a callback to be called when the queue is truly closed.
I'm also retaining self, to make sure my object doesn't go away before the queue is done calling my object. I then use the capture_cleanup callback to release self.

```
-(void) startCameraCapture {
    _camSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    if (_previewLayer == nil) {
        _previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_camSession];
    }
    _previewLayer.frame = self.compView.bgView.frame;   
    [self.compView.bgView.layer addSublayer:_previewLayer];

    // Get the default camera device
    AVCaptureDevice* camera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // Create a AVCaptureInput with the camera device
    NSError *error=nil;
    AVCaptureInput* cameraInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:camera error:&error];
    if (cameraInput == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error to create camera capture:%@",error);

    }

    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* videoOutput = [[[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init] autorelease];

    // create a queue to run the capture on
    _captureQueue=dispatch_queue_create("captureQueue", NULL);
    dispatch_set_context(_captureQueue, self);
    dispatch_set_finalizer_f(_captureQueue, capture_cleanup);

    // setup our delegate
    [videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_captureQueue];

    dispatch_release(_captureQueue);

    // retain self as a workouround a queue finalization bug in apples's sdk 
    // per Stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741121/how-to-properly-release-an-avcapturesession
    [self retain];

    // configure the pixel format
    videoOutput.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                 nil];

    // and the size of the frames we want
    [_camSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];

    // Add the input and output
    [_camSession addInput:cameraInput];
    [_camSession addOutput:videoOutput];

    [cameraInput release];

    // Start the session
    [_camSession startRunning];     
}
```

Here the capture_cleanup callback:

```
 static void capture_cleanup(void* p)
    {
        LiveCompViewController* ar = (LiveCompViewController*)p;
        [ar release];  // releases capture session if dealloc is called
    }
```

Then my cleanup code looks like this:

```
-(void) stopCameraCapture {
[_camSession stopRunning];
    [_camSession release];
    _camSession=nil;    

    // Remove the layer in order to release the camSession
    [_previewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    _previewLayer = nil;

}
```

The problem I'm having is that removing the _previewLayer from the superlayer in stopCameraCapture is causing the following console error:

> "...modifying layer that is being finalized..."

But I need to remove the layer so that it gets released and deallocated so that it releases the _camSession which in turn releases the dispatch_queue and then finally calls my capture_cleanup callback which finally releases self.

I don't understand why I'm getting the console error and how to fix it. Why is the Layer being finalized at the time I'm calling `[_previewLayer removeFromSuperlayer]` if self.dealloc hasn't been called.

Note: self is a viewController and I haven't popped it yet, so it is retained by the NavigationContoller.

Answer (score 3):

Try stopping the session before releasing:

```
[captureSession stopRunning];
```